# Choose a file (image, pdf, doc) and upload to server flutter android

Tags: flutter

I'm working with ASP.NET rest APIs. The task is I have to choose only one thing i.e image, pdf, docs file and send it to server. For picking files, I'm using the following library
**file_picker: ^3.0.3**

After successfully picking the file when I send it to the server, the response from the server is **403 forbidden.**

```
// this is picking image code
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

              if (result != null) {
                PlatformFile file = result.files.first;

                ApiClient.apiClient.uploadDocumentApi(file.path);
              }
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: kPrimaryColor,
              elevation: 0.0,
            ),
            child: Text('Select'),
          ),

// this is API code
Future<void> uploadDocumentApi(String filePath) async {
    print('pathh: ' + filePath);
    String url = 'www.example.com';
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'POST',
      Uri.parse(url),
    );
    // request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('', filePath));
    request.files.add(
      http.MultipartFile(
        '',
        File(filePath).readAsBytes().asStream(),
        File(filePath).lengthSync(),
        filename: filePath.split("/").last,
      ),
    );
    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('success');
      print(response.stream.bytesToString());
    } else {
      print('fail');
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error code indicates its related to authentication of your request. make sure your set your jwt correctly in your request header if needed and check it with backend side